# JSON-LD to PHP array

Tags: php, json

**How do I convert JSON-LD extracted from website to a PHP array.**

This is the Error I'm getting with the following code---

> "Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in
>   /Users/lightingsystem/sigclub/signatureclub/public/json/json2php.php
>   on line 12 {"

--code--

```
$json = '{ "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "LodgingBusiness", "name":"Breakerwood Suites", "amenityFeature":"A nice place to sleep", "audience":{ "@type":"Audience", "audienceType":"All" }, "checkinTime":"16:00", "checkoutTime":"10:00", "petsAllowed":"No", "availableLanguage":"", "openingHours":"", "paymentAccepted":"", "address":"2323 Bowers St.,New Orleans,LA,USA,69969", "image": "https://www.picturebook.com/resort2.jpg", "telephone":"Resort telephone number: 504/339-4543" }';

$coded = json_encode($json);

$data = json_decode($coded, true);

echo $data['name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `json_encode` is wrong because `$json` is **already** in the JSON format.

So what happens is: your JSON gets converted to JSON again, returning a JSON string.

Remove the `json_encode` call and your code works as expected.

```
<?php

$json = '{ "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "LodgingBusiness", "name":"Breakerwood Suites", "amenityFeature":"A nice place to sleep", "audience":{ "@type":"Audience", "audienceType":"All" }, "checkinTime":"16:00", "checkoutTime":"10:00", "petsAllowed":"No", "availableLanguage":"", "openingHours":"", "paymentAccepted":"", "address":"2323 Bowers St.,New Orleans,LA,USA,69969", "image": "https://www.picturebook.com/resort2.jpg", "telephone":"Resort telephone number: 504/339-4543" }';

$data = json_decode($json, true);

echo $data['name'];
```

Note:

- You can get the last JSON error with **[`json_last_error_msg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)**

Comment: Great! Thank you!